# How to check which thread crashed?

Tags: lldb

Given I've opened core file via `lldb`, how can I check which thread crashed?

```
$ lldb -c core.45583 -o 'bt all' | grep -A2 'thread #'
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fffc6b7641a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fffc6b75867 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
--
  thread #2, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffc6c65214 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread
--
  thread #3, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffc6b7641a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fffc6b75867 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
--
  thread #4, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffc6b7dc12 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pselect + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fffc6b7a815 libsystem_kernel.dylib`pselect$1050 + 82
--
  thread #5, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffc6bd368b libsystem_malloc.dylib`get_tiny_previous_free_msize + 59
    frame #1: 0x00007fffc6be83b6 libsystem_malloc.dylib`tiny_free_no_lock + 80
...
  thread #19, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fffc6163b69 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 41
    frame #1: 0x00007fffb0d002a2 CFNetwork`HTTPResponseMessage::setResponseURL(__CFURL const*, unsigned char) + 66
```

As it seems all the threads have `SIGSTOP`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [it should be the one with  `mach_msg_trap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html) but looks like you'll need to do some hex dump hunting to recover the real call stack...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are actually 2 threads with `mach_msg_trap`, how do you know which one and why? Which commands I should run to check that?

Comment: I don't know; try to look further in the call stacks. Anyway, it's not really an RE question.